# Reusing custom validation methods in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: validation, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.x

I want to validate in several models if a given IP and subnet make together a valid network.

I wrote this custom validation function for one model:

```
public function isValidNetwork($check=null){
    if(isset($this->data[$this->name]['ip']) && isset($this->data[$this->name]['subnet'])){
        $iph = new IpHandler();
        return $iph->isNetwork($this->data[$this->name]['ip'],$this->data[$this->name]['subnet']);
    }
    return false;
}
```

What is the best practice to reuse this function in other models? Maybe to move the function to `AppModel`?

But there is another problem, that the keys are not always the same.

Is it possible to overwrite the validation rule to pass only the necessary parameters? For example:

```
'subnet' => array(
        'rule' => array('isValidNetwork','ip','subnet'),
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'No valid network given'
    )

public function isValidNetwork($ip, $subnet){...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of reusing your validation method is to implement it in `AppModel`, or in a custom Behavior.

With regards to allowing your custom validation method to validate different field names, the Cookbook suggests that you use `extract_values()`.

This example has been taken from the docs:

```
class Post extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'slug' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumericDashUnderscore',
            'message' => 'Slug can only be letters,' .
                ' numbers, dash and underscore'
        )
    );

    public function alphaNumericDashUnderscore($check) {
        // $data array is passed using the form field name as the key
        // have to extract the value to make the function generic
        $value = array_values($check);
        $value = $value[0];

        return preg_match('|^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]*$|', $value);
    }
}
```

But I guess you could as well use the extra arguments as the keys to extract the relevant data.

In the `$validation` array:

```
'subnet' => array(
    'rule' => array('isValidNetwork','ip','subnet'),
    'required' => true,
    'message' => 'No valid network given'
)
```

And in your method:

```
public function isValidNetwork($check, $ipFieldName, $subnetFieldName){
    if(isset($this->data[$this->name][$ipFieldName]) && isset($this->data[$this->name][$subnetFieldName])){
        $iph = new IpHandler();
        return $iph->isNetwork($this->data[$this->name][$ipFieldName],$this->data[$this->name][$subnetFieldName]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to make use of a single extra parameter, you can do the following:

```
'ip' => array(
    'rule' => array('isValidNetwork','subnet'),
    'required' => true,
    'message' => 'No valid IP/network given'
)
```

Your custom validation method would look as follows:

```
public function isValidNetwork($check, $subnetFieldName){
    list($ip) = array_values($check);

    if(!empty($ip)) && !empty($this->data[$this->name][$subnetFieldName])){
        $iph = new IpHandler();
        return $iph->isNetwork($ip,$this->data[$this->name][$subnetFieldName]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

See [Cookboox 2.x: Data Validation: Adding your own Validation Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods)

Comment: I know that possibility. But then i have an unused parameter in my method. That is not clean code. But if it is not possible to avoid the $check parameter, i agree with you.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the `$check` parameter to reference one of the fields, and specify the other through a single extra parameter. This would tie your custom validator to a main field type (e.g. `ip`), leaving the extra parameter for the other field (e..g `subnet`).

Comment: Edited the answer to include this modification.